# Home button stops video recording

Tags: ios, iphone, avfoundation, video-recording, home-button

I am using AVFoundation and pressing the home button on my device stops it recording from the front camera. Is there a way for me to keep recording from the front camera even after the home button is pressed? Why does pressing the home button stop me from recording?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You cannot record video while your app is in the background.

Allowed background tasks:

- Apps that play audible content to the user while in the background, such as a music player app
- Apps that record audio content while in the background.
- Apps that keep users informed of their location at all times, such as a navigation app
- Apps that support Voice over Internet Protocol (VoIP)
- Apps that need to download and process new content regularly
- Apps that receive regular updates from external accessories

Read Implementing Long-Running Background Tasks:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW24